# Git hooks not firing

Tags: windows, git

I have git running on a local Windows PC and everything is working perfectly; I have Jenkins and Phing working to automate my build and test processes, however the final step is to automatically kick off the build once a commit is made in git.

I have tried adding post-commit to my local repo's .git/hooks directory with the following:

```
curl http://localhost:8198/git/notifyCommit?url=c:\scm\myProject
```

If I run this command directly from the command line Jenkins kicks off the job fine, however when I push a commit it does not fire.

Additionally I have tried adding the script at https://github.com/MestreLion/git-tools/blob/master/git-restore-mtime to the hooks directory in the main repo named post-checkout so that I can add the commit time as the file modified time when cloned. This is also not firing.

Do I need to do something specifically in git or my repo to allow hooks to fire? If not, is there anywhere in particular I can look to start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to do something specifically in git or my repo to allow hooks to fire?

Mainly:

- make sure the hook is executable (`chmod 775 .git/hooks/post-commit`, which isn't actually needed on Windows)
- make sure '`curl`' is in the `%PATH%` (which is the case if your <`c:\path\to\git`>\bin is in said path)
- make sure your command-line test did use the curl package with Git, and not another curl like the one package with [GoW Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) (if you have GoW installed)
- add, if it helps, a `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of your post-commit script (since it will be executed by the msys bash)
- the name must be post-c ommit (case sensitive, no extension like `.sh` or `.bat`)

The Op mentions an [issue with missing quotes around the `curl` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20812499/6309).
This is consistent with the fact that it is called in an msys bash session, and **[shell quoting](https://www.mpi-sb.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html)** rules apply.
I would make sure the '`\`' character isn't interpreted as well.
See "[Which quoting method protects which characters?](https://www.mpi-sb.mpg.de/departments/rg1/teaching/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html#para:sh-which)":

> Double quotes (`"..."`) protect everything except double quotes, backslashes, dollar signs, and backquotes, until the next double quote.
>   A backslash can be used to protect `"`, `\`, `$`, or  within double quotes.
>   A backslash-newline pair disappears completely; a backslash that does not precede `"`, `\`, `$`, , or newline is taken literally.

In your case, I would use:

```
curl "http://localhost:8198/git/notifyCommit?url=c:\\scm\\myProject"
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, both hooks are executable. On Windows I have set the security on both to allow "Full Control" to "Everyone".

Comment: @JordanWindebank ok, is any of my other suggestions useful?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Turns out I had an error in my curl statement and needed to put quote marks around the url. It's working fine now. As for the post-checkout, turns out this doesn't work as I expected it to but have been able to get it to fire. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed to put quote marks around the URL to get it to set the correct local path:

```
curl "http://localhost:8198/git/notifyCommit?url=c:\scm\myProject"
```

This now works as expected.